# Insert image to Picasa in Python Google App Engine Sdk through urlfetch

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http, picasa, urlfetch

I try to insert an image from a Flex application to picasa web through Google App Engine Sdk.  I want to do a simple urlfetch instead of the python client library. The code i following:

```
    def Insert(self, sessionToken, album_or_uri, title, filename_or_handle):
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url=album_or_uri,
                                method=urlfetch.POST,
                                follow_redirects=True,
                                payload=StringIO(filename_or_handle),
                                headers={'Authorization': 'AuthSub token="' + sessionToken + '"',
                                'Content-Length': str(len(filename_or_handle)),
                                'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
                                'Slug': title
                                })
```

The data pass to "filename_or_handle" is a ByteArray image.  However, it is not successful.  I have no idea what the problem is.  Please advice.  Thanks.

The solution is following:

```
def Insert(self, sessionToken, album_or_uri, title, filename_or_handle):
    image = filename_or_handle.read()
    contentLength = len(image)
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=album_or_uri,
                method=urlfetch.POST,
                follow_redirects=True,
                payload=image,
                headers={'Authorization': 'AuthSub token="' + sessionToken + '"',
                'Content-Length': contentLength,
                'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
                'Slug': title
                })
```

Thanks, Johnson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Payload should be a string, not a file-like object. How it should be encoded depends on the API you're calling - see the docs for the API to determine that, and any other headers etc you need to set. It's unlikely you need to base64 encode it - just pass the contents of the image in directly.

If you're still having problems, you'll have to be more specific than "it is not successful" - what response do you get?

Comment: @Johnson, thanks for your reply.  I pass the data from a flex application through pyamf.  The image is loaded as a ByteArray into the the flex app and I pass it to the App Engine.  The base64 is just a testing.  Please see the update also.

Comment: @michael I answered the question after your update. As I said, you should load the image data as a raw string, and pass it in directly as the payload. And provide more details if you're still having trouble.

Comment: @Johnson, maybe it is a stupid question.  Is the bytearray image data acceptable in my case.  Thanks.

Comment: @michael Python doesn't have 'ByteArrays'. Perhaps you should include the snippet in your question to encompass how you're getting the data.

Comment: @Johnson, the code is included in the update for your reference.  Thanks.

Comment: @michael This doesn't explain how you get the image data in your code. I'm not asking about the flex code, I'm asking where 'filename_or_handle' comes from.

Comment: @Johnson, after I get the _byteArr from the flex code, I pass it to pyPhoto.Insert() in flex.  This function will pass it to the Gae through the gateway in pyamf, and then the Insert() function in Gae will be called.  For the pyPhoto.Insert() function, please the update.  Thanks.

Comment: @michael Then you need to get the image data with `filename_or_handle.read()`, and pass that in. You also need to call `len` on the data itself, not on the handle.

Comment: @Johnson, thanks for your time and advice.  I update the code, see the Update 4, but it still do not work.

Comment: @michael You're still wrapping the data in a StringIO. Don't. As I've said several times, we need more details than "it does not work" in order to help. What goes wrong?

Comment: @Johnson, I have tried both image = StringIO(filename_or_handle.read()) and image = filename_or_handle.read().  The result is same as the Update 1, no image insert, code 200, TypeError.

Comment: @michael I can't help you further until you actually paste your stacktrace and all the relevant code.

Comment: @Johnson, please see the Update 5.

Comment: @michael Neither of those is a stack trace. You need to check the admin console's log page, and see what exception you're getting with the complete stacktrace.

Comment: @Johnson, I am using Python SDk ver1.4.3, where I can find the  admin console's log page.

Comment: @michael On the dev_appserver, at `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin`. In production, at `http://appengine.google.com/`. Have you done the App Engine tutorials and read the docs? You should know this in order to be able to debug your app.