# GAE - POST an image from BlobStore to an outside server using urlfetch

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I have a `Google AppEngine` app (written in `Python`) in which I have stored a lot of images inside the BlobStore (which I access via `images.get_serving_url( blob_key )`).

I am trying to figure out how to use `urlfetch` to `POST` one of these images to a third party site (Flickr actually; I know I have to authenticate the request, which I have figured out already).

I'm fairly new to GAE, and I'm trying to learn the blobstore best I can.

Does anyone have any idea on how to grab the image binary data from the blobstore (give either the `get_serving_url` or the blob key), and then `POST`ing it inside a `urlfetch` request?

I've been googling all afternoon, but can't find any suitable examples.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the whole blob / image using the blob reader :

```
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
```

Comment: Any idea how I could then use this inside a urlfetch post? The example BlobReader documentation (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass) is still quite confusing to me.

Comment: Put the blob and other arguments in the url encoded payload of the post. I do not know which arguments the Flickr webservice expects.

Comment: your info combined with the answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555323/insert-image-to-picasa-in-python-google-app-engine-sdk-through-urlfetch) dies exactly what I was trying to learn to do. Many thanks!